# React native, linking Youtube videos for normal view

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app. When i press video card it opens youtube video.

```
Linking.openURL(video_url);
```

In android, Youtube app and videos always started in mini view.

[image]

I tested with Android 8 and Android 14.

How can i open videos in normal view? I don't want to show video in my app. I just want to open youtube app in normal view.